# Is the theory of decoherence general or specific to the physical implementation?

Tags: decoherence, superconducting-quantum-computing

I’m looking for the theoretical calculations of charge and transmon qubit decoherence specifically, but at a high level I'm wondering how decoherence is approached generally.

I’ve seen explanations based on finding the time until the Rabi oscillations decay off as well as arguments that end with a Lindblad equation. Are these all equivalent ways of getting the decoherence rate, or does the approach to decoherence calculations depend on the approach to Quantum Computing (charge qubit vs transmon qubit vs spin qubit vs ion trap etc...)

So to restate my question, when people talk about Linblad vs Rabi, is this two side of the same coin (this is what I'm doubting), or are there specific circumstances that warrant these approaches to decoherence calculations?

Comment: Doesn't Некто mean "nobody" in Russian?

Comment: I want to answer this question but I feel that it is not specific enough. There are at least two questions here. The first is whether decoherence can be calculated at all, or if it's just empirical. Certainly decoherence can be calculated, and you even say that in the next paragraph where you mention the Lindblad equation. Then you ask whether there's a general scheme for calculating decoherence. If you could make the question somewhat more specific, I'm sure I can answer.

Comment: As Daniel suggests, I think it's best if you ask only one question per post i.e. ask the second part of your question in a separate post. In the current form it does look overly broad and demands an excessively long answer cf. [help/on-topic](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).